# Reading Latin date description in 18th century German church record?

Tags: germany, 18th-century, date

This record of my x-gg's brother shows a wedding date recorded from the church calendar.

[image]

What does this mean? (I read the header as "Fer. II Pascs." -- is that perchance Easter Monday?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the date as "Fer. II. Pasch.", that is the 2nd feastday of Easter -- your interpretation of the Monday following Easter Sunday is valid.

Fer.  = ferias (holiday)
Pasch. = Pascha (Easter)

For the numbering, compare the "12 Days of Christmas", which counts Christmas (25 Dec.) as #1 and Epiphany (6 Jan.) as #12.

Comment: Of course, as we found out in my other question, this date is for the reading of the banns. Unfortunately the actual date of the wedding was never recorded.

Comment: So the "cop. d. " in the right margin is the whole note and not cropped? Could the smudged ink to the right of Pasch. be a date?